# Can't connect to ejabberd server anymore : unauthorized

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I am using Adium to connect. recently i added few modules and updated yml file then restarted server. I cant connect anymore , stacktrace :

```
2016-03-28 13:41:02.335 [info] <0.2572.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:333 (#Port<0.29607>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:60680 -> 127.0.0.1:5222
2016-03-28 13:41:02.344 [debug] <0.2583.0>@ejabberd_receiver:process_data:284 Received XML on stream = <<"<?xml version='1.0' ?>">>
2016-03-28 13:41:02.345 [debug] <0.2583.0>@ejabberd_receiver:process_data:284 Received XML on stream = <<"<stream:stream to='localhost' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'>">>
2016-03-28 13:41:02.345 [debug] <0.2584.0>@ejabberd_c2s:send_text:1838 Send XML on stream = <<"<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='10052708892550611418' from='localhost' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>">>
2016-03-28 13:41:02.345 [debug] <0.2584.0>@ejabberd_c2s:send_text:1838 Send XML on stream = <<"<stream:features><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='AC6YpUkEgZqi0CJQw6bRvljBJUI='/><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>">>
2016-03-28 13:41:02.372 [debug] <0.2583.0>@ejabberd_receiver:process_data:284 Received XML on stream = <<"<auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='DIGEST-MD5' xmlns:ga='http://www.google.com/talk/protocol/auth' ga:client-uses-full-bind-result='true'/>">>
2016-03-28 13:41:02.372 [debug] <0.2583.0>@shaper:update:120 State: {maxrate,1000,0.0,1459151650401468}, Size=162
M=81.0, I=27.194
2016-03-28 13:41:02.373 [debug] <0.2584.0>@ejabberd_c2s:send_text:1838 Send XML on stream = <<"<challenge xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>bm9uY2U9IjMyNDcwNzA4Nzg5NTMxMzQ0NzIiLHFvcD0iYXV0aCIsY2hhcnNldD11dGYtOCxhbGdvcml0aG09bWQ1LXNlc3M=</challenge>">>
2016-03-28 13:41:02.430 [debug] <0.2583.0>@ejabberd_receiver:process_data:284 Received XML on stream = <<"<response xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>dXNlcm5hbWU9ImthcmFuYWh1amEiLHJlYWxtPSJsb2NhbGhvc3QiLG5vbmNlPSIzMjQ3MDcwODc4OTUzMTM0NDcyIixjbm9uY2U9IjM5NTNlYzc3MTQ1OTE1MjY2MjczODI0M2QxIixuYz0wMDAwMDAwMSxxb3A9YXV0aCxkaWdlc3QtdXJpPSJ4bXBwL2xvY2FsaG9zdCIscmVzcG9uc2U9ZGEwY2JkNzEwYWU4ZWRmYTdlZTJjZjc2ZjdmNmYwYTcsY2hhcnNldD11dGYtOA==</response>">>
2016-03-28 13:41:02.430 [debug] <0.2583.0>@shaper:update:120 State: {maxrate,1000,996.7635947479173,1459151650482731}, Size=342
M=340.8967200647646, I=4.604
2016-03-28 13:41:02.430 [debug] <0.2451.0>@ejabberd_odbc:sql_query_internal:554 SQL: "select password from users where username='karanahuja'"
2016-03-28 13:41:02.943 [info] <0.2584.0>@ejabberd_c2s:wait_for_sasl_response:935 ({socket_state,gen_tcp,#Port<0.29607>,<0.2583.0>}) Failed authentication for karanahuja@localhost from 127.0.0.1
2016-03-28 13:41:02.943 [debug] <0.2584.0>@ejabberd_c2s:send_text:1838 Send XML on stream = <<"<failure xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><not-authorized/></failure>">>
2016-03-28 13:41:02.958 [debug] <0.2583.0>@ejabberd_receiver:process_data:284 Received XML on stream = <<"</stream:stream>">>
2016-03-28 13:41:02.958 [debug] <0.2583.0>@shaper:update:120 State: {maxrate,1000,998.7827033629674,1459151650824457}, Size=16
M=15.98054693395935, I=196.114
2016-03-28 13:41:02.958 [debug] <0.2584.0>@ejabberd_c2s:send_text:1838 Send XML on stream = <<"</stream:stream>">>
2016-03-28 13:41:02.958 [debug] <0.2584.0>@ejabberd_socket:send:184 Error in gen_tcp:send: {error,closed}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the logs, it looks like you really have wrong password. While changing your configuration file, you may have change the way it authenticates. You should first try using your previous config file to check if this solves your issue and then carefully checks the diff of your changes.